# Quadratic Form for Matrix with Sum

Tags: quadratic-forms

I just had a pretty basic question. Suppose you have the quadratic form:

$$(u+x)^t V (u+x)$$

If you expand this out, you get something along the lines of

$$u^t V u + x^t V x + u^t V x + x^t V u$$

Is there a way to simplify this; i.e. does the above become:

$$u^t V u + x^t V x + 2u^t V x$$

and why is that the case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: True if $V$ is square symmetric matrix. When it is not, you get truth when replacing $V$ by its symmetric part, $(V+V^T)/2.$ Finally, the contrribution of the skew-symmetric part $S=(V-V^T)/2$ is nil, because $x^t S u = -u^t S x.$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Will. If $V$ is a square symmetric matrix how do I show that this is true?

Comment: The transpose of a 1 by 1 matrix, which is a number, is itself. $W$ symmetric, $(x^t W u)^t = u^t W^t x = u^t W x$

Comment: Great, thanks Will, that was of great help!